# What precautions should one take when building a model in two stages?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, arima, trend, smoothing

My data has too many features to be estimated with a single predictive model (see [How to model a stochastic trend in the response variable of a regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242650/how-to-model-a-stochastic-trend-in-the-response-variable-of-a-regression)). In consequence, I'm considering a time series method (exponential smoothing, kernel, continuous AR, etc) to detrend the observations and then fitting a regression on the raw residuals (a model to explain the "distance from the trend").

In a simple case, I assume running ARIMA and then a regression on the residuals is less efficient than running ARIMAX. In this case there's no single model for my data, so I was wondering what precautions I should take and how much efficiently I'm losing.

Comment: sorry I am not quite sure what you mean with "efficient".

Comment: @stats0007 Probably efficiency isn't the exact term (it's usually related to variance). In two-stage models, you don't use all the information in simultaneous to estimate all the parameters. Following the ARIMAX vs ARIMA+lm example, the latter doesn't provide the covariance among the estimates for the autoregressive part and the external regressors. I've run a few simulation exercises and ARIMA+lm feels more like a hack.